# unbinding click from specific element among classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have come across a scenario. i have some elements with same classes. All of them have same eventhandler on click. If some condition is true, i need to unbind click function from specific element.
 Here is my snippet

```
     $(".del_grp").die().live('click', deleteGroup);
                        $(".del_grp").css('opacity','1');
                        $(".del_grp").css('cursor','pointer');
                        if($('.map_unit').length === 1){
                            $('.grp').each(function(){

                                if($(this).next().children().length !==0 ){
                                    $(this).find('.del_grp').die('click');
                                    $(this).find('.del_grp').css('opacity','0.5');
                                    $(this).find('.del_grp').css('cursor','default');
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

Here, the `CSS` properties are working properly, the the `die()` is not working

Comment: the doc says `Note: In order for .die() to function correctly, the selector used with it must match exactly the selector initially used with .live().`

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, use of .die() (and its complementary method, .live()) is not recommended. Instead, use .off() to remove event handlers bound with .on() - [Document jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

Comment: I would check what versions of Jquery you are using aswell, both `.live()` and `.die()` are deprecated. `.on()` and `.off()` are the replacements.

Comment: Why unbind a delegated event? Instead, just filter inside handler condition and react according it inside the click handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.off()` instead of `.die()` and `.on()` instead of `.live()`. It works properly. See the demo below

```
var deleteGroup = function () {
    console.log('del group clicked');
}; 
$(".del_grp").off().on('click', deleteGroup);
$(".del_grp").css('opacity','1');
$(".del_grp").css('cursor','pointer');
if($('.map_unit').length === 1){
    $('.grp').each(function(){
        console.log('for each group');
        if($(this).next().children().length !==0 ){
            $(this).find('.del_grp').off('click', deleteGroup);
            $(this).find('.del_grp').css('opacity','0.5');
            $(this).find('.del_grp').css('cursor','default');
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/xz8Up/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use .unbind() on the objects?

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$( "#foo").unbind( "click" );
```